# PHP header firstname surname

Tags: php, header

I'm stuck on creating a system that collects both the user's first and second name. I've created two pages, htest1.php and htest2.php. htest1.php contains a form for the users to enter their details. The second page htest2.php has a script to find the data sent using the form and return this data to displaued in the first page.

Here is my code for htest1.php:

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['fname'])){
        echo "Hello".$_GET['fname'];
    }
?>

<form method="post" action= "htest2.php"
    <label for="firstname" Enter your name</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" />
    <inout type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

My code for the htest2.php:

```
    <?php
    $fname = $_POST['firstname'];
    header ("Location: htest1.php?fname=$fname");
    ?>
```

I've successfully returned the first name. Just need advice on how to do both the first name AND surname

Comment: your so close, im sure you can find the answer yourself

Comment: I honestly don't know how to do it. Multiple names in isset? Don't have a clue

Comment: I dont understand how you codded the above and dont know what to do

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can be great

htest1.php

```
<?php
    $l_sFirstName = (isset($_GET['fname']) ? striptags( $_GET['fname'] ) : "";
    $l_sLastName = (isset($_GET['lname']) ? striptags( $_GET['lname'] ) : "";
    if( $l_sFirstName != "" OR $l_sLastName != ""){
        echo "Hello ".$l_sFirstName . " " . $l_sLastName ;
    }
?>

<form method="post" action= "htest2.php"
    <label for="firstname" Enter your name</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" />
    <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" />
    <inout type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

htest2.php

```
<?php
    $fname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lastname'];
    header ("Location: htest1.php?fname=$fname&lname=$lname");
?>
```